# How to change button value on click?

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks

I'm trying to do button which value is set to `''` by default and when clicking button it's own value should change. Here is what I tried already.

First I did new hook state which sets value to `''`:

```
const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState('');
```

Then I did event handler which should set new value depending on current value. Value is set `''` by default, on click button value should change to `value1`, click again and value should change to `value2`, and last when value is set to `value2` it should change back to default `''`. First time I click button value actually changes to `value1` but then value doesn't change anymore:

```
const valueHandler = (e) => {
  setButtonValue(e.target.value);

  if (e.target.value === '') {
    setButtonValue('value1');
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'value1') {
    setButtonValue('value2');
  }
  if (e.target.value === 'value2') {
    setButtonValue('');
  }
}
```

And last I did actual button which should change it's own value:

```
<button value='' onClick={valueHandler}>
  Click to change value
</button>
```

Any ideas how to make button change it's own value on click? Also if somebody have better solution for this I'm listening :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState('')

const valueHandler = (e) => {
   if (e.target.value === 'value1') {
      setButtonValue('value2')
   } else {
      setButtonValue('')
   }
}

return (
   <button value={buttonValue} onClick={valueHandler}>
      Click to change value
   </button>
)
```

You didn't use the `buttonValue` in the `<button>` before.

Comment: I knew it was as simple as this :D Well.. that was solid six hour struggle. Thank you!